# Transfer answer from duplicate unregistered user account

Tags: support, user-accounts, new-users

I answered a question as not registered user, after that I registered, is it possible to transfer the not-registered answer to my registered account?

The answer gave is here:
[Is there a difference in the infrared absorption spectrum of a greenhouse gas when pure and when mixed with non-greenhouse gases?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/448675/is-there-a-difference-in-the-infrared-absorption-spectrum-of-a-greenhouse-gas-wh/538815#comment1219794_538815)

Comment: I think there is some way to contact support to get it done, but I am not familiar with the specifics, so I will leave others who are more knowledgeable to give an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Please use the ["Contact"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link in the footer of the page and choose "I need to merge user profiles" as the reason and explain your case. SE will handle the merge manually.